# Need to understand the Logic of Playframework

Tags: database, playframework, playframework-2.0

i have a simple question. if i use `play.db.ebean.Model` to have my Model extend from Model, how can i save it into DB? more clearly: in Django, the database file is created and i save the object, it will be saved into db file and i dont do any sql statements for retrieving or saving objects.. how does this work in playframework?

lets say i have configured my database file in application.conf file like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/microblogdb"
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password=""
```

now i have a database file somewhere in system.

now i have a Class User which extends Model as i stated above. now i want to save one User object into db. so i will do like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.username = "testusername";
user.fullname = "userfullname";
user.save();
```

what will happen after that `save()` call? can i now directly see my User object in database file?

appreciate any help!

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will, if you didn't do any mistakes.

Make sure that in `application.conf` you also UNcommented the line:

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Check sample applications in sample folder of the Play package you downloaded. For an example ComputerDatabase (not JPA version) to see the basics of working with Ebean.

What's more you can create constructor(s) in your model to simplify creating User model:

```
public User(String username, String fullname) {
    this.username = username;
    this.fullname = fullname;
}
```

And use it in controller as:

```
User user = new User("doniyor", "Doniyor The Great");
user.save();
```